# Why doesnt getchar() stop reading strings in C?

Tags: c, string, input, scanf, getchar

I want the user to be able to input a number n and then the program will read n strings from the user. But now the program wont stop reading strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRING_MAX 10

int main (void)
{
    char string[STRING_MAX];
    int count;
    int total;
    int n, i;
    int chr;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        do {
            count = 0;
            total = 0;
            while ((chr = getchar() != EOF)&& (chr != '\n'))
            {
                if (count < STRING_MAX - 1)
                    string[count++] = chr;
                total += 1;
            }
            string[count] = '\0';
        } while (total > STRING_MAX - 1);
        printf("The input string was:\n\t%s\n", string);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have an operator precendence problem here

```
chr = getchar() != EOF
```

this is evaluated as

```
chr = (getchar() != EOF)
```

because the `!=` operator has [higher precendence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) than the assignment operator `=`, so you just need to add parentheses like this

```
(chr = getchar()) != EOF
```

**Tip**: Check the return value from `scanf()` before accessing `n`, because if the input is invalid you would try to use `n` while it's uninitialized which would cause undefined behavior.

Comment: i changed the parenthese but still theres another problem, the first getchar is skipped.. so if i type 2 it only reads 1 string.. i think scanf is leaving the newline in the input stream

Comment: @Yiannis you are right, `scanf()` does leave the newline in the input stream, just make a loop with `getchar()` until you remove it from the stream before starting the other loop.

Comment: what kind of loop? what condition should be in the loop?

Comment: ohh nice! is this like a standard thing to do in c?

Comment: It's not standard, it's appropriate for this situation.

Comment: @MattMcNabb absolutely right `chr` should be declared outside the loop.

Comment: As @MattMcNabb noted `do {int chr = getchar();} while ((chr != EOF) && (chr != '\n'));` should be `int chr; do {chr = getchar();} while ((chr != EOF) && (chr != '\n'));`

Comment: tis ok i had already declared it before so i didnt declare it again inside the loop